# Auto assign issues does not function reliably

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.6

I am having trouble setting up issue auto-assign features of development cockpit to work. We are setting up LTS version 5.6.4.

For now, I have manually created users who's email address exactly matches the SCM(git) email address. Only one of 5 users I have created get any issues assigned.  The user that has things showing in dev cockpit is the first user i created if that matters.

I created the project and ran a few scans before creating the users. these scans are against the same code so i expect nothing new to show up between my test scans.  Does this feature only work when a "new" issue is located?  if so is there any way to back-load/assign issues that didn't have a sonarqube user at that point in time?

On that note,  we hope to use LDAP eventually.  in our old sonarqube server (4.5.3 i think), the ldap plugin had some pretty bad limitations.  namely the system was not aware of the ldap users until a specific user logs in at least once.

If it turns out that users must be present in the system at the time an issue is discovered, and the LDAP plugin still has the same limitation, the developer cockpit will be useless for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues are auto-assigned, if possible, at creation.

To assign existing issues, I would:

- search by Author
- use Bulk Change to assign the retrieved issues

Comment: I suppose that works,  for such an expensive option (Eur 7000) i would have hoped automatic assign would be more ...automatic.

Can't you make the sonar-scanner devcockpit reassign?

BTW, i confirmed the ldap issue exists.   unless someone logs in once before their issues are discovered, the remain unassigned.

Comment: Not to nit-pick @bkilgore but issue assignment is a core feature & thus free. And imagine the converse - you unassign issues to yourself because they're just not a priority right now, and at each analysis they're reassigned to you.